# What would cause intermittent DomainKey-Status: failures?

Tags: email, domainkeys

Every week, we send something like a small newsletter.  Sometimes, the header in the newsletter says

```
DomainKey-Status: bad (test mode)
```

Sometimes it says

```
DomainKey-Status: good (test mode)
```

All the other headers in the email are the same (besides expected time and message id differences).  None of the email server configuration has changed.  What would cause this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Temporary DNS issues at recipient end could be causing the problems. If you want to know if the problem is at your end or recipient end, look at [this](http://www.allaboutspam.com/email-server-test). If it happens consistently, then you need to look at your Domain Keys signing software.

Without knowing which software is being used, it is tough to tell. But a good starting point will be the logs produced by the software.